Audio Recording/Screen Recording in Flutter Application
I am creating a Voice Conferencing App using Flutter for Android and I want to add a feature for recording the audio that's played from my app (the audio of the other people on the call) and also whatever the user says in his microphone at the same time. But I have tried different things but it doesn't seem to work.
I managed to achieve the audio recording from user microphone using the "record" flutter package but I am not able to record the rest of the audio. Even screen recording is not working, where I planned to extract the audio from it later on(though it will be pretty inefficient). I have also tried using Kotlin method channels for the same but failed to achieve my goal.

Recording audio from both the microphone input and the audio output (what's played from the app, including other participants' voices in a conferencing app) simultaneously can be challenging due to platform limitations and privacy concerns.
In Android, capturing audio output from other apps or the system generally requires special permissions or system-level access, which is typically restricted for security and privacy reasons. Similarly, capturing audio output using Flutter or any other framework isn't directly supported because of platform restrictions.
However, there are some possible workarounds and alternative approaches you can consider:
Audio Mixing on Server: Instead of capturing audio locally on the device, you can send microphone input and audio output (received from other participants) to a server, where the mixing can be done and then recorded. This would require you to have control over the server-side implementation.
Screen Recording: As you mentioned, recording the screen might capture the audio output along with the microphone input. However, this approach can be inefficient and might not provide the desired quality. Also, extracting audio from a video file can add complexity.
Platform-Specific Solutions: Investigate platform-specific APIs or libraries available in Android for capturing audio output. This might involve using Java or Kotlin code directly within your Flutter app using platform channels.
Custom ROMs or Rooted Devices: On rooted devices or custom ROMs, there might be options to access audio streams from other apps. However, this approach is not recommended for production apps and might violate platform policies.
Reconsider Privacy and Permissions: Keep in mind the privacy implications of capturing audio output from other apps or the system. Users may not be comfortable with an app accessing audio from other sources without explicit permission.
Consult with Legal Experts: Depending on your app's use case and jurisdiction, there may be legal implications to consider, especially regarding privacy and recording audio without consent.
